# amp-experiment and Google Tag Manager

Tags: amp-html

I've implemented an `amp-experiment` on my website which works fine. Now obviously I want to collect and analyze the data for this experiment. I have been searching and trying for a few hours, but can't seem to figure out how I can get the information about which experiment is running for a visitor using the Google Tag Manager.

[The documentation](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-experiment/amp-experiment.md#reporting) shows how to use the `amp-pixel` to collect data, but I was wondering if there is a way to use GTM. I've tried to create a custom AMP Variable in GTM with `variant` and `VARIANT` as values, but it doesn't seem to associate any data with this variable.

Any pointer would be very much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Well, if you check the [amp-experiment](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-experiment) documentation, you will not find any word here that this amp-experiment can work with the [Tag Manager](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/). I found here a [blog](https://thenextweb.com/insider/2016/10/25/marketing-the-tnw-way-16-using-google-tag-manager-in-amp/) that uses a Google Tag Manager with AMP, but I cannot find here that you can use it with the amp-experiment. So just check this blog to know more about Tag Manager with AMP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @KENdi. I've also found the blog you mentioned but as you wrote, there is no mention of amp-experiments. I'll keep exploring and post here if I find something.